# How to close jquery dialog inside Java code

Tags: java, jquery, dialog, tapestry

I use jquery dialog in my Tapestry project. And currently I need to refresh the page to close dialog in my Cancel button click event.

```
@XHR
private Object onSelectedFromCancel() {
    editingObject = null;
    return this;
}
```

But it's not good for user experience to refresh entire page just to cancel. So, how can I close jquery dialog without refresh the page inside Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your approach. Jquery dialog is in client, and you should close it in client with some js code. Use jquery.

Comment: Although this is right, this looks more of a comment other than an answer.